# Linear program of 0-1 knapsack problem and proof of integer

Tags: determinant, linear-programming

I have some questions about the knapsack problem.

1. How can the 0-1 knapsack problem described as a linear program?
2. How to proof that the solution of the 0-1 knapsack problem are integer? (I'm thinking about the determinant)

Thanks!

Comment: The determinant of a matrix is always a sum of products of the entries of the matrix. The sum or product of integers is an integer.

Comment: Hi @MJD, the fact that the sum or product of integers is an integer is true, but is it also a mathematical proof?